# Regex match whole word not working

Tags: c#, regex

apologies for the rookie question.

I have a small journal where I am letting users comment on stuff that I post and am converting certain characters to smileys.

so **:)** becomes an image `<img src='\smiley\smile.png' />` 
and **:d** becomes `<img src='\smiley\big-smile.png' />` and so on and so forth.

Now, recently, one of my friends posted an educational link which had a `:d` in the url and my smiley regex jumped at the link and broke it into pieces, with a big smile image.

You get the Idea.

So I changed my regex from `:d` to `\b:d\b` and expected it to match whole word, if `:d` is all by itself. Guess what? the regex picks up NOTHING now.

[here is a sample demonstration of what I am talking about](http://regexr.com?2u9qu)

How do I get the regex to match only `:d` on its own? thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You will need to use look behind and look ahead matches on beginning / end of string and whitespace as the characters you are trying to match won't necessarily trigger the usual word boundary rules.

use`(?<=^|\s):d(?=$|\s)` this pattern should work for all of your matches eg `(?<=^|\s):\)(?=$|\s)`

Answer (score 3):

That's because `\b` matches word boundaries. It works when you put it behind the `:d`, because the `d` is considered a word. `:` is not considered a word character, and thus is not a word boundary. Fix it with a lookbehind for whitespace or an anchor:

```
(?<=^|\s):d\b
```

Edit: as Bob Vale pointed out, this also applies if you are matching a smiley like `:/`, `/` does not trigger a word boundary. You have to do the same thing, but with a lookahead:

```
(?<=^|\s):d(?=$|\s)
```